# Перегрузка операторов >> и << в шаблонном классе как дружественных функций

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
const size_t SIZE = 4;
```

Вот мой класс:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T arr[SIZE][SIZE];
     friend  ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);
     friend  istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T> &);
    void initialize();// функция которая заполняет матрицу как единичную

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>&);
    const Matrix& operator=(const Matrix<T>&);
    const Matrix& operator*(const Matrix<T>&);
    void  operator*=(const Matrix<T> &);
    T* operator[](int row);
};
```

Тут реализованы все остальные работающие операции.

И тут ошибка линковки в реализации этих двух операций:

```
template< typename T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
    for (int i(0); i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            os << rhs.arr[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

template< typename T>
istream & operator>>(istream&  is, Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
    for (int i(0); i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            is >> rhs.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

С чем связано возникновение ошибки?

Comment: Зачем вы индексируете массив переменной типа int? Для этого есть size_t.

Почему бы не сделать SIZE параметром шаблона, а не заводить глобальную константу?

Моя реализация матричных операций на C++ с шаблонами - https://habrahabr.ru/post/249101/

Comment: @gbg на тему `int`а в размере `QVector` [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619863/why-qvectorsize-returns-int).

Comment: @alexolut, это Вы привели в качестве защиты `int`? Если да, то это неубедительно. Ребята, которые работали и работают над Qt не являются авторитетом, совершенно.

Comment: @ixSci это я привел в качестве альтернативной точки зрения, с обоснованием. Я бы для размера выбрал беззнаковый тип. Про авторитет немного странно звучит, т.к. ребята, разрабатывающие Qt являются (по-определению) авторитетами в Qt. И наличие знакового типа обусловлено в том числе спецификой Qt. То, что их идеология не совпадает с идеологией `std::`, не должно, имхо, являться предметом споров здесь. Как говорится, в чужой монастырь со своим уставом ...

Comment: @alexolut, просто их «альтернативность» создаёт проблемы, в совмещении кода Qt с кодом стандартной библиотеки и boost. Но они упорные, я им баг на эту тему создавал несколько лет назад, но они не захотели менять это в 5-й версии. Я не собираюсь обсуждать их решение, т.к. оно было сделано давно и сейчас мы с этим живём. Но в современном коде совершенно нет нужды использовать int в качестве индекса.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> friend  ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);
> friend  istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T> &);
> ```

На эти объявления компилятор пишет предупреждения:

```
prog.cpp:13:64: warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<T>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
      friend  ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);
                                                                ^
prog.cpp:13:64: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

Если их исправить так:

```
template <typename T1> friend  ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T1> &);
template <typename T1> friend  istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T1> &);
```

то всё компилируется: http://ideone.com/fd6jzV

Comment: У вас цитата поверх кода, так и задумано?)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, да я процитировал код из вопроса - это нормально. А вот два плюса за неверный на тот момент ответ - не очень :)

Comment: Спасибо большое:) все работает. Если вам не сложно можете пояснить почему вы стали использовать еще один шаблонный тип данных T1?

Comment: @Kirill, в таком случае следует принять ответ зелёной галочкой. Можно ещё проголосовать за него, если хватает рейтинга.
А по поводу T1 - потому что компилятор сказал "Предупреждение ... дружественное объявление ... объявляет нешаблонную функцию ... если это не то что вам требуется ... убедитесь, что шаблонная функция объявлена ранее ..." Возможно, есть более правильное решение, т. к. моё делает дружественными функции с любым типом матриц, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: А ведь компилятор был более прав, чем я думал...

Answer (score 19):

### Почему код не работает

Делая следующие объявления:

```
friend  ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);
friend  istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T> &);
```

Вы говорите компилятору, где-то есть функции, которые принимают потоки первым аргументом и `Matrix<T>` вторым. Но `Matrix<T>` здесь не является шаблоном, вопреки тому, что может показаться — шаблоном является класс `Matrix`, а `Matrix<T>` здесь является вполне конкретной реализацией, которая будет известна в момент инстанциации шаблона. Более того, никакого кода вообще не существует, пока шаблон не был инстанциирован.

Исходя из этого, наши friend-декларации только тогда вступают в силу, когда происходит инстанциация шаблона. Давайте, к примеру, создадим `Matrix<int>`. Это даёт нам следующий код, сгенерированный для нашего шаблона:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<int> &);
friend  istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<int> &);
```

Т.е. как Вы можете видеть, у нас есть две **нешаблонных** friend-декларации. С другой стороны у нас есть реализация **шаблонного** оператора(приведу только один для краткости):

```
template< typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

Если Вам кажется, что объявление в классе и определение вне его должны быть как-то связаны, то это не так. Это две **совершенно разные функции**(одна шаблонная, а другая нет), а т.к., согласно ADL(argument-dependent lookup), при вызове оператора, поиск надлежащей функции будет проведён в классе, то компилятор находит нашу friend-декларацию:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<int> &);
```

Но вот реализации этой декларации нет, отсюда и ошибка компоновщика. В лоб, для типа `int`, это можно было бы исправить следующий образом, надо исправить нашу реализацию на следующую:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix<int> & rhs)
{
    ...
}
```

Теперь наш оператор перестал быть шаблоном и поэтому он является реализацией нашей friend-декларации, для шаблона инстанциированного для `int`.

### Как починить

Разумеется, нам это не подходит — не будем же мы писать реализацию под каждый тип инстанциации. Поэтому нам нужно так написать friend-декларацию, чтобы она всегда учитывала тип `T`. Как это сделать? Нужно завести шаблонный оператор, как Вы и делали раньше, т.е. оставляем старую реализацию:

```
template< typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
   ...
}
```

Но теперь, в классе `Matrix`, мы добавим в друзья *специализацию* этого шаблона:

```
friend ostream& operator <<<T>(ostream & os, const Matrix & rhs);
friend istream& operator >><T>(istream &, Matrix &);
```

А так как мы объявляем другом специализацию, то мы должны вынести определение(или только объявление) общего шаблона до класса `Matrix`, т.е. весь Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix;

template< typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
    ...
}

template< typename T>
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream&  is, Matrix<T> & rhs)
{
    ...
}


template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T arr[SIZE][SIZE];
    friend  ostream& operator <<<T>(ostream &, const Matrix &);
    friend  istream& operator >><T>(istream &, Matrix &);
    ...
};
```

---

Ещё один правильный вариант, с минимумом изменений, может быть такой:

```
friend  ostream& ::operator << (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);
friend  istream& ::operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T> &);
```

Но он работает только в студии, clang&gcc не принимают этот код.

Comment: Круто! Шаблоны и тонкости их семантики в плюсах — очень нетривиальная тема.

Comment: @VladD, я бы даже сказал, что шаблоны в C++ живут своей жизнью и никто не знает всех их тонкостей. У меня постоянно волосы шевелятся, когда приходится выходить за рамки базового использования шаблонов

Comment: Угу, одно только инопланетное SFINAE стоит много седых волос.

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативный вариант указан [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators).

Мы хотим объявить friend'ом для `Matrix<T>` не весь шаблон оператора, а только одну его спецификацию с типом `T`. Для этого нам нужно предварительно объявить *полный* шаблон оператора. А для этого нам надо предварительно объявить шаблон класса.

Кроме того, мы должны указать, что наш оператор — шаблонный. Это приводит к такому коду:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix;

template<typename T>
ostream & operator<< (ostream &, const Matrix<T> &);

template<typename T>
istream& operator >> (istream &, Matrix<T> &);

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T arr[SIZE][SIZE];
    // объявляем friend'ом конкретную специализацию
    friend ostream& operator << <> (ostream &, const Matrix &); // обратите внимание на <>
    friend istream& operator >> <> (istream &, Matrix &);

    ...
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/LbBd5U

---

Большая часть этого решения по праву принадлежит @Qwertiy, который понял и объяснил, чего и почему не хватает компилятору.

Comment: Обсуждение [в чате](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27701602#27701602)