# Перегрузка опператора '<<' C++ с использованием шаблонов

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, шаблоны-с++

Проблема с перегрузкой оператора ***<<***. Реализую класс для работы с кольцевой очередью и перегружаю оператор, чтобы выводить очередь. Когда пытаюсь вызвать строку ***cout << B*** выдаёт ошибку, не подскажите, в чём тут проблема. И доп. вопрос : зачем при написании функций часто указывается ***const***, после описания передаваемых значений (как например у меня в функции show)?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
typedef int bufor_type;

using namespace std;

template <typename type>
class Bufor
{
private:
    type *Arr = new type;
    int Start;
    int End;
    int Arr_Size;
    bool circle;
public:
//______________________________________________________
    Bufor():Arr_Size(0),Arr(NULL),End(0),Start(0){}
    Bufor(int b_size, type *b_arr, int b_start,int b_end)
    {
        set(b_size,b_start,b_end);
        Arr = b_arr;
    }
//______________________________________________________
    void set(int b_size,int b_start,int b_end)
    {
        Arr = new type[b_size];
        Arr_Size = b_size;
        Start = b_start;
        End = b_end;
        circle = false;
    }
//_______________________________________
    void Show(ostream& stream)const
    {
            for (int i = Start; i < End-1; i=(++i)%Arr_Size) stream << Arr[i] << " ";
    }
//____________________________________________________
//operators
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& st, const Bufor& A);
};
template<typename type>
ostream& operator<<(const ostream& st, const Bufor<type>& A)
{
    A.show(st);
    return st;
}
int main()
{
    Bufor<bufor_type> A;
    int *temp = new int;
    Bufor<bufor_type> B(3,temp,0,0);
    A = B;
    cout << B;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с того, что
1. исправьте объявление друга на

```
template<class U>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& st, const Bufor<U>& A);
```

2. уберите const из его определения:

```
template<typename type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& st, const Bufor<type>& A)
```

3. В теле напишите `A.Show(st)`, а не `A.show(st)` - С++ различает регистры...

О дополнительном `const` - при вызове функции-члена ей кроме аргументов в скобках неявно передается еще один - сам объект, `this`, грубо говоря. Это `const` и говорит о том, что этот объект может быть константным. Т.е., грубо говоря, функция-член обещает ничего в самом объекте не менять, кроме того, что объявлено как `mutable`.

Comment: Спасибо, а зачем запись _template<class U>_

Comment: Потому что так положено в C++ - это шаблонный друг, ему надо свой `template<typename...>`

Comment: Я имею в виду, почему передаётся `class U`

Comment: @koshachok Чтобы не совпадало с `type` в вашем объявлении `Bufor`. Я обычно использую T, U, V... Вот по-привычке и написал U :)

Comment: А можно было написать `typename U`? Почему именно передаётся `class`?

Comment: @koshachok А, да, конечно - в данном контексте эти ключевые слова абсолютно взаимозаменяемы. Дело вкуса.

Comment: @koshachok Вообще, на самом деле не обязательно объявлять именно так друга шаблонного класса, [можно и без U](https://ideone.com/6IPSLb)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive О, буду знать... Спасибо!

Comment: @Harry Да не за что. На самом деле тут раньше был [один интересный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9), который умудрился собрать довольно неплохую базу решений несколько схожей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& st, const Bufor<type>& A)
{
    A.show(st);
    return st;
}
```

const после функции означает, что функция не может изменять переменные того объекта, к которому она принадлежит. Следовательно из этой функции можно вызывать только аналогичные константные функции.