# Доступ к привату через friend

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, шаблоны-с++

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::ostream;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

template <class T> class Array
{
    int size;
    T *arr;
public:
    Array(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        arr = (T*)calloc(size,sizeof(T));
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        free(arr);
    }
    template <T> friend ostream operator << (ostream &stream, const Array<T> array);

};
template <class T> ostream operator << (ostream &stream, const Array<T> array)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
        stream<<array.arr[i]<<" ";
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    Array <int> arr (5);
    cout<<arr;
}
```

Выдает ошибку на cout:

> C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp||In instantiation of 'std::ostream
>   operator<<(std::ostream&, Array) [with T = int; std::ostream =
>   std::basic_ostream]':|
>   C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|35|required from here|
>   C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|9|error: 'int Array::size' is
>   private| C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|27|error: within this
>   context| C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|10|error: 'int*
>   Array::arr' is private|
>   C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|28|error: within this context|
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h|786|error:
>   'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private|
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_ios.h|66|error:
>   within this context|
>   c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream|58|note:
>   synthesized method 'std::basic_ios::basic_ios(const
>   std::basic_ios&)' first required here |
>   C:\Users\Работа\Desktop\array.cpp|29|note: synthesized method
>   'std::basic_ostream::basic_ostream(const
>   std::basic_ostream&)' first required here | ||=== Build failed:
>   6 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения проблемы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::ostream;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

template <class T>
class Array;

template <class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, const Array<T>& array)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
        stream << array.arr[i] << " ";
    return stream;
}

template <class T>
class Array
{
    int size;
    T *arr;
public:
    Array(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
        arr = (T*)calloc(size, sizeof(T));
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        free(arr);
    }
    friend ostream& operator << <T>(ostream &stream, const Array& array);

};

int main()
{
    Array <int> arr(5);
    cout << arr;
}
```

P.S. Подробно о том, почему именно так смотрите в ответах к [вопросу-дубликату](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Зачем давать ответ, одновременно признавая что это дубликат?

Comment: @alexolut На случай, если человек совсем обленится вникать в ответы к дубликату и захочет просто сделать _copy/paste_.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите, чтобы *любая* специализации шаблона оператора `<<` имела доступ к приватным членам *любой* специализации шаблона `Array`, то

```
template <typename T> class Array
{
  ...
  template <typename U> friend ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Array<U> &array);
};

template <typename T> ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Array<T> &array)
{
  ...
}
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы доступ имела именно и только специализация `<<` *для того же самого типа* `T`, для которого специализирован `Array`, то

```
template <typename T> class Array;
template <typename T> ostream &operator << (ostream& stream, const Array<T>& array);

template <typename T> class Array
{
  ...
  friend ostream &operator << <T>(ostream &stream, const Array<T> &array);
};

template <typename T> ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Array<T> &array)
{
  ...
}
```

Более того, в последнем случае можно воспользоваться дедукцией шаблонных аргументов и "сократить" friend-объявление до

```
  friend ostream &operator << <>(ostream &stream, const Array<T> &array);
```

т.е. убрать `T` из `<T>` в объявлении оператора.

Вам в данном случае нужен именно второй вариант. Первый тоже будет работать, но он избыточен.