# Друзья в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пишу оболочку над `std::set` с операторами `<<` и `>>`. Компилятор не может найти определения для шаблонных друзей:

```
template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
class MySet;

template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, MySet<KType, PType, AllocType>& set)
{

}

template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MySet<KType, PType, AllocType>& set)
{

}

template<typename KType, typename PType, typename AllocType>
class MySet
{
public:
  typedef std::set<KType, PType, AllocType> set_type;
  friend std::istream& ::operator >> (std::istream&, MySet&);
  friend std::ostream& ::operator << (std::ostream&, const MySet&);
private:
  set_type s;
};
```

Пробовал также объявлять друзьями специализации операторов как с заполненными `<>`, так и с путыми - также не выходит.

Нашёл [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495141/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9), однако у меня не 1 шаблонный аргумент, и применить описанные там способы не удаётся.

Подскажите, как сделать правильно.

P.s.: компилятор `MSVC`

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде "друзьями" класса `MySet` объявляются *нешаблонные* функции с параметрами соответствующего типа. Таких функций у вас в коде вообще нет, по каковой причине ваши объявления "друзей" фактически не делают вообще ничего. Ваши предварительно объявленные *шаблонные* функции при этом "друзьями" класса не становятся.

[**Замечание:** разнообразные компиляторы, похоже, ведут себя именно так (в частности, GCC 5 открыто пишет об этом в предупреждении), однако внимательное рассмотрение текста стандарта (см. комментарии) как будто требует компилируемости и исходного варианта, использующего qualified-id в объявлениях "друзей".]

Вам нужно объявить в качестве "друзей" либо конкретные специализации ранее объявленных *шаблонных* функций

```
template<typename KType, typename PType, typename AllocType>
class MySet
{
  ...
  friend std::istream& ::operator >> <>(std::istream&, MySet&);
  friend std::ostream& ::operator << <>(std::ostream&, const MySet&);
  ...
```

либо вообще все их специализации

```
template<typename KType, typename PType, typename AllocType>
class MySet
{
  ...
  template <typename I, typename J, typename K>
    friend std::istream& ::operator >> (std::istream&, MySet<I, J, K>&);
  template <typename I, typename J, typename K>
    friend std::ostream& ::operator << (std::ostream&, const MySet<I, J, K>&);
  ...
```

Однако последний вариант тут избыточен и совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: Вы уверены в том, что запись автора объявляет друзьями только нешаблонные функции? Как насчёт _[temp.friend]p1(1.3)_?

Comment: @ixSci: Хм... Да, я только сейчас заметил, что в исходном коде использовано qualified-id, а не unqualified-id. И вроде бы третий пункт в 14.5.4/1 должен работать. Но GCC и clang почему-то не берут такой код. Что же имеется в виду этим третьим пунктом.

Comment: Никто не берёт, студия берёт слегка модифицированный вариант(у меня в ответе есть). Поэтому я не понимаю, либо не совсем правильно понимаю стандарт, либо все компиляторы неправильно это имплементировали.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459283/friend-a-template-specialization-without

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#674

Comment: Похоже что код таки должен был компилироваться.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки! Да, видимо очередная непопулярная фича, которую не сильно стремятся имплементировать правильно. Благо есть простое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите сделать друзьями класса конкретные специализации шаблонных функций, поэтому Вам нужно явно это указать. Вот так будет выглядеть корректная запись:

```
friend std::istream& operator >><>(std::istream&, MySet&);
friend std::ostream& operator <<<>(std::ostream&, const MySet&);
```

Теоретически, Ваша версия тоже должна работать, но по факту она нигде не работает. Так что либо я неправильно понимаю теорию, либо компиляторы неправильно обрабатывают этот случай. Слегка модифицированная версия работает в студии, но больше нигде:

```
friend std::ostream& ::operator <<(std::ostream&, const MySet<KType, PType, AllocType>&);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для задания шаблонной свободной функции в качестве друга шаблонного же класса, в определении класса нужно объявить эту функцию шаблонной. Т.е. добавить `template`. Приведу пример для Вашего случая, но ограничусь одним оператором:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <set>

template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
class MySet;

template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MySet<KType, PType, AllocType>& set)
{
   std::cout << "op<<\n"; return os; 
}

template<typename KType, typename PType, typename AllocType>
class MySet
{
public:
  typedef std::set<KType, PType, AllocType> set_type;
  template <typename K, typename P, typename A> // *** Эта строка важна! ***
  friend std::ostream& ::operator << (std::ostream&, const MySet<K, P, A>&);
private:
  set_type s;
};

int main()
{
    MySet<int> ms;
    std::cout << ms;
}
```

<kbd>[Пример выполнения](http://rextester.com/JDUD23049)</kbd> в компиляторе от MS.